# How to enlarge window in website without maximize button

Tags: firefox

I often need to use a particular website for work. This website requires the user to enter data in a window that doesn't have a maximize button or any other controls that let you change the size of the window - just a scroll bar. Unfortunately, the window is only about 75% the size of a fully maximized one. I find this very inconvenient so I was wondering if there's any other way to change the size of the window.  My browser of choice is Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Many windows applications will allow management of the window size with keystrokes. You may be able to accomplish your objective by pressing Alt-spacebar, followed by the letter x. The first key combination opens the window management menu, the second selects Maximize.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't do it. It opened the menu for Firefox but not the data entry window.